# Merging 2 columns in a new CSV, don't want to copy over occupied cells with new empty cells

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to copy numbers from columns 4 and 5 and put them into a single column. If one of the two columns has a number in it, the other column is empty. I would like to relocate all of these numbers into column 5. In the new column 4 I would like the number 933 if the number was originally in column 4, and the number 966 if the number was originally in column 5. Here is what I have so far:

```
            if not row[4].strip():
                Tamt = row[5]
            row[4] = '933'
            if not row[5].strip():
                Tamt = row[5] 
                # struggling because this one writes over the numbers just written from row[4] with the
                # blank cells that existed in row[5] 
                row[4] = '966'
            row[5] = Tamt
```

The problem is that I think the part of the code where I am retrieving and writing the numbers from column 5 into the new csv is writing over the numbers relocated from the original column 4 with the blank cells that existed in the original column 5. Is there any way to copying over these blank cells?

Comment: Do you know how to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/index.html)? There is functionality for merging datasets together outlined on [this page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html), but the most typical case will combine them into different columns. The framework allows for making columns using your own function too though, which would make this a trivial problem.

Comment: I will look into how to use it. Does it matter that I have not been using pandas to create the rest of this program? Do I need to have opened this CSV using pandas and translate the rest of my code to use pandas?

Comment: @Reedinationer I am struggling to figure out how to open the CSV that I want to write to using pandas. Could you provide me with an example of the code to do so?

Comment: Pandas is basically a python module that lets you easily manipulate tables. It has a bit of a learning curve, but usually what would take 50 lines becomes 5 using pandas, and the computations have been vectored to increase the speed. To read data from a csv is a simple `df = pd.read_csv(file_name)` [the docs have options you can specify like whether there are headers](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-read-csv-table)